# NHibernate gets crashed by a magic string

Tags: nhibernate

Here is my trivial program:

```
public class Entity
{
  public virtual long Id { get; set; }
  public virtual string Payload { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
  static void Main( string[] args )
  {
    var config = new Configuration().Configure();
    var sessionFactory = config.BuildSessionFactory();
    using ( var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession() )
    {
      var entity = new Entity { Payload = "'))" }; 
      session.Save( entity );
    }
  }
}
```

As long as Payload property is assigned any innocent string such as 'Hi there' everything works as expected. However this particular magic string **'))** makes NHibernate throw an exception: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection' when it tries to save the entity.

I wonder why NHibernate cares of the parameter content. It really shouldn't.

Or maybe something is very wrong with this sample?

NHibernate version is 2.1

SQL script:

```
create table tblEntity
(
  EntityId BIGINT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
 ,Payload VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
)
```

Mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="MyNamespace.Entity, MyAssembly" 
         table="tblEntity">
    <id name="Id" column="EntityId" unsaved-value="0">
      <generator class="identity"/>      
    </id>
    <property name="Payload"/>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

NHibernate settings:

```
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect</property>
    <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string_name">Main</property>
    <property name="connection.isolation">ReadCommitted</property>
    <property name="default_schema">dbo</property>
    <property name="format_sql">true</property>
    <property name="query.substitutions">true=1;false=0</property>
    <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu</property>
    <mapping assembly="MyAssembly"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Nothing special as you can see, not too much room for mistakes.

### Stack Trace

```
System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument argument, ExceptionResource resource)
System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException()
System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index)
NHibernate.AdoNet.Util.BasicFormatter.FormatProcess.CloseParen()
NHibernate.AdoNet.Util.BasicFormatter.FormatProcess.Perform()
NHibernate.AdoNet.Util.BasicFormatter.Format(String source)
NHibernate.AdoNet.Util.SqlStatementLogger.LogCommand(String message, IDbCommand command, FormatStyle style)
NHibernate.AdoNet.Util.SqlStatementLogger.LogCommand(IDbCommand command, FormatStyle style)
NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.LogCommand(IDbCommand command)
NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.Prepare(IDbCommand cmd)
NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.ExecuteReader(IDbCommand cmd)
NHibernate.Id.IdentityGenerator.InsertSelectDelegate.ExecuteAndExtract(IDbCommand insert, ISessionImplementor session)
NHibernate.Id.Insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.PerformInsert(SqlCommandInfo insertSQL, ISessionImplementor session, IBinder binder)
NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Insert(Object[] fields, Boolean[] notNull, SqlCommandInfo sql, Object obj, ISessionImplementor session)
NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Insert(Object[] fields, Object obj, ISessionImplementor session)
NHibernate.Action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.Execute()
NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.Execute(IExecutable executable)
NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractSaveEventListener.PerformSaveOrReplicate(Object entity, EntityKey key, IEntityPersister persister, Boolean useIdentityColumn, Object anything, IEventSource source, Boolean requiresImmediateIdAccess)
NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractSaveEventListener.PerformSave(Object entity, Object id, IEntityPersister persister, Boolean useIdentityColumn, Object anything, IEventSource source, Boolean requiresImmediateIdAccess)
NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractSaveEventListener.SaveWithGeneratedId(Object entity, String entityName, Object anything, IEventSource source, Boolean requiresImmediateIdAccess)
NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.SaveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveEventListener.SaveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.EntityIsTransient(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveEventListener.PerformSaveOrUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.OnSaveOrUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.FireSave(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Save(Object obj)
```

Comment: How does the query looks like, that gets generated by NHibernate ?  You can make sure NH outputs the generated queries by setting the show_sql property to true in the NH configuration.

Comment: There is no query. NH Profiler displays empty session, log file is empty as well, so I think exception occurs before the query is passed to SQL server.

Comment: Are you using a logger? I just tried this it does not throw for me, however I am using NH 3.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have looked up the changes made to

> src/NHibernate/AdoNet/Util/BasicFormatter.cs

there was an issue in NH 2.1 that caused this behavior, this was fixed in 2.1.1.GA.

Bugtracker: [NH-1992](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-1992)

Changeset on github: [Commit](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/commit/856f35049492bdde943468e19e13b884c5345da2)

Comment: That's right, I have to either upgrade NHibernate or turn off `format_sql` settig.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it might be a bug with NHibernate. When a command is logged (because you have `show_sql` set to true) it will write out your command and it will look something like this:

```
insert into tblEntity (Payload) VALUES(@p0); @p0 = ''(('
```

The logger then tries to tokenize the string and gets confused by the parentheses. Try submitting a bug to the [NHibernate JIRA](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH). In the meantime you can try turning off show_sql

Comment: Everything is fine with `show_sql`, and as you can see it was not set in my example. The problem was with `format_sql` option.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with NHibernate, however what you are describing looks as if it might be the result of inadvertant [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) Hopefully the linked wiki page might help.

Comment: As far as I understand NHibernate relies on ADO.NET facilities when it comes to protect against sql injection. ADO.NET doesn't object to this magic sequence of characters if it's transferred to the database via SqlParameter.