# NHibernate Throwing a Strange Error

Tags: nhibernate, log4net

When I call _repository.DbContext.CommitChanges() on IRepository, it gives me the following error: Field not found: 'NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.log'

I am not sure where this error is coming from or how to determine why this happening?  Anyone have any ideas or thoughts?

Comment: A form of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7178259/nhibernate-gets-crashed-by-a-magic-string ?

Comment: I tried telling it not to format sql and not to show it, but that did not work.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Are you using MVC mini profiler to profile NHibernate queries?

Comment: I see this problem when using MVC mini profiler and nhibernate (via the contrib nuget package)